# git-ftp config settings with password ending in #

Tags: git-ftp

My git-ftp information in my .git/config file is (obviously this is dummy info):

```
[git-ftp]
   user = myName@mydomain.com
   url = ftp.mydomain.com
   password = PassWord#
```

When I catchup my local repo with my ftp

```
git ftp catchup
```

I get the error:

```
curl: (67) Access denied: 530
Tue, Oct 06, 2015 10:17:04 AM: fatal: Could not upload file: '.git-ftp.log'., exiting...
Tue, Oct 06, 2015 10:17:04 AM: fatal: Could not upload., exiting...
```

If I instead I do this from the command line:

```
git ftp catchup -u myName@mydomain.com -p 'PassWord#' ftp.mydomain.com
```

I do not get the error.

I have tracked this problem to being the ending # on my password.  I have tried changing my config line for the password to be in quotes:

```
password = 'PassWord#'
```

But this does not work.

Obviously I just change my password so it will work, but I want to figure out why the # is keeping the config file from working right, but it works fine from the command line.  Anyone know how I can resolve this so config file works properly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing # introduces a comment in the config file.  Not sure if there's a way to escape it.

Comment: *smacks forehead* of course.  Having a can't see the forest for the trees day.  And I did figure out it can be escaped.  See answer.  Thanks @EricJ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Eric J pointed out, the # is a comment tag in the .git/config file.  I had already tried using single quotes around the password and it had failed.  Ashamed to say I did not think to try double quotes.

Further testing revealed using double quotes "" around the password allowed the config file to work with the password having a #.

```
[git-ftp]
  user = myName@mydomain.com
  url = ftp.mydomain.com
  password = "PassWord#"
```